# Due to Keys are getting duplicated one <ht:news_item> tag are getting skipped in every <item> ! how to avoid that?

Tags: web-scraping, beautifulsoup, tags, google-trends

[googletrend daily serach](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UT6wa.png)
[rss feed of google trend](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2iviJ.png)
I am trying fetch the google trending seraches as shown in the first image i want to fetch  + two <ht:items>. In my code i am able to fetch only  and only one <ht:items> next are getting skip.
links:

website link : https://trends.google.com/trends/trendingsearches/daily?geo=IN
rss feed- https://trends.google.com/trends/trendingsearches/daily/rss?geo=IN

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import csv
import pandas as pd

url = "https://trends.google.co.in/trends/trendingsearches/daily/rss?geo=IN"
resp = requests.get(url)
soup = BeautifulSoup(resp.content,'xml')

items = soup.findAll('item')
news_items = []  

for item in items:
    news_item = {}
    news_item['title'] = item.title.text
    news_item['approx_traffic']=item.approx_traffic.text
    news_item['description'] = item.description.text
    news_item['link'] = item.link.text
    news_item['pubDate']=item.pubDate.text
    news_item['picture'] = item.picture.text
    news_item['picture_source'] = item.picture_source.text
    news_item['news_item_title']=item.news_item_title.text
    news_item['news_item_snippet'] = item.news_item_snippet.text
    news_item['news_item_url'] = item.news_item_url.text
    news_item['news_item_source'] = item.news_item_source.text
    news_item['news_item_title']=item.news_item_title.text
    news_item['news_item_snippet'] = item.news_item_snippet.text
    news_item['news_item_url'] = item.news_item_url.text
    news_item['news_item_source'] = item.news_item_source.text
    news_items.append(news_item)
print(news_items)

print(len(news_item))

df = pd.DataFrame(news_items)

df.to_csv('my_csv.csv',columns=["title","approx_traffic","description","link","pubDate","picture","picture_source","news_item_title","news_item_snippet","news_item_url","news_item_source","news_item_title","news_item_snippet","news_item_url","news_item_source"])
```

Comment: You're rewritting `news_item_title`, `news_item_snippet`, ... keys. Dictionaries can contain only unique keys.

Comment: Okay i will remove that after that how do i overcome with it ? and print all the <ht:news_item> i.e news_item_title etc !